# jscrollpane not visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I've got a lot of jquery madness going on with my page, and i'm wondering if that's the reason jscrollpane doesn't show.

See http://jasondaydesign.com and click on the sculpture menu item on the left and then on the remaining div on the screen.

Without jscrollpane, the text is scrollable.

However, with jscrollpane enabled, nothing shows.

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try reinitialising jScrollPane after showing the box which contains it. So change this line:

```
$(this).find('.expandable').show('normal')
```

To:

```
$(this).find('.expandable').show(
    'normal',
    function()
    {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    }
);
```

**Previous answer**

From a quick look in the network inspector of Firebug it looks like:

http://jasondaydesign.com/css/jquery.scrollpane.css

Is currently a 404. That might be causing the problem?

Comment: Hey Vitch - that seemed to do the trick - Thanks! But of course now there is a new error. If you scroll only partway down and let go of your click, it registers it as a closing click which then closes that div.

Comment: That's not really related to jScrollPane. You should be more specific when you add the "click to close" handler. Or you can check the target of the event when you get a click and if it is related to `.is('.jspDrag')` then don't close the element...